# How to extract specific patterns from HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract some specific parts of an HTML with repeated pattern inside.

Pattern looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        itemJS.ProductsList({"Status":"true",
            "description":"sku_01",
            "id": "00000001"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately this HTML has many javascripts inside and i'm interested in the above pattern only .
Using BeatifulSoup library, i can get all "javascripts" in HTML with `find.All` function:

```
soup.findAll('script', attrs={"type": "text/javascript"})
```

But how to extract these specific patterns only ?
I would like to obtain this "dict" as results:

```
({"Status":"true",
 "description":"sku_01",
 "id": "00000001"
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find()` with `text=` parameter, then `re`/`json` module to decode data.

For example:

```
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        itemJS.ProductsList({"Status":"true",
            "description":"sku_01",
            "id": "00000001"
        });
    });
</script>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

# locate the <script>
t = soup.find('script', text=lambda t: 'ProductsList' in t).contents[0]

# get the raw string using `re` module
json_data = re.search(r'itemJS\.ProductsList\((.*?)\);', t, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)

# decode the data
json_data = json.loads(json_data)

# print the data to screen
print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "Status": "true",
    "description": "sku_01",
    "id": "00000001"
}
```

---

EDIT: If you have multiple `<scipt>` tags, you can do:

```
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        itemJS.ProductsList({"Status":"true",
            "description":"sku_01",
            "id": "00000001"
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        itemJS.ProductsList({"Status":"true",
            "description":"sku_02",
            "id": "00000002"
        });
    });
</script>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for script_tag in soup.find_all('script', text=lambda t: 'ProductsList' in t):
    json_data = re.search(r'itemJS\.ProductsList\((.*?)\);', script_tag.contents[0], flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
    json_data = json.loads(json_data)
    print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
```

This prints:

```
{
    "Status": "true",
    "description": "sku_01",
    "id": "00000001"
}
{
    "Status": "true",
    "description": "sku_02",
    "id": "00000002"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, but how to manage your solution if i have multiple patterns inside this HTML ?   something like :  `for i in soup.find('script', text=lambda t: 'ProductsList' in t).contents[0]`